# Why is it necessary to set a netmask of 255.255.255.255 for “alias” addresses in FreeBSD?

Tags: networking, freebsd, alias, interface

From FreeBSD handbook on the topic of [virtual hosts](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-virtual-hosts.html):

> For a given interface, there must be
>   one address which correctly represents
>   the network's netmask. Any other
>   addresses which fall within this
>   network must have a netmask of all 1s
>   (expressed as either 255.255.255.255
>   or 0xffffffff).

Can anybody explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [page](http://docs.huihoo.com/darwin/opendarwin/articles/network_config/ar01s03.html) contains a good explanation imho:

> Since aliases are, in a sense,
>   duplicate tags, the system needs to
>   know whether the subnet represented by
>   the tag is new, and this is indicated
>   by the netmask. With a "normal"
>   netmask, the system is told this is a
>   new subnet, and it can then set up
>   internal tables correctly. If the
>   subnet is not new, the tables will get
>   set up incorrectly if the netmask is
>   "normal".
>
> With a netmask of 255.255.255.255, the
>   system knows this is a duplicate of an
>   existing subnet, and therefore will
>   assign the address as if it were
>   assigned to the loopback interface,
>   with the "point-to-point" mask.
>
> Assigning a netmask of 255.255.255.0
>   will, in most cases, appear to work.
>   However, the internal tables will not
>   be set up correctly, and if the alias
>   is removed, problems may ensue. This
>   can be overcome by adding appropriate
>   host routes when the alias is added,
>   and removing the routes when the alias
>   is removed. However, the system works
>   correctly with the "point-to-point"
>   netmask, and maintenance is easier.

Comment: However a "point-to-point" address is a /31 or a /30. A /32 describes a single host.

Comment: @adamo: [In practice point-to-point links are typically implemented using /30 networks, or occasionally by /32 and point-to-point explicit host routes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference)

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can set the netmask you think is useful.

**But, if** you change the netmask from /32 you will also need to set a route. If you follow the recommendation you can omit setting a route.

Answer (score -1):

Well the FreeBSD manpage on ifconfig is not very helpful:

> If the address is on the same subnet
>   as the first network address for this
>   interface, a non-conflicting netmask
>   must be given.  Usually 0xffffffff is
>   most appropriate.

But what the above means is that a /32 mask makes this a specific network (The simplest network, a single host, is described by a /32 mask). Having the same netmask as the physical interface does not do any harm, as they are two interfaces on the same network.

Now imagine the alias having a mask that describes a superset network than that of the physical interface, e.g. the physical being 192.168.0.1/25 and the alias 192.168.0.2/24. Is 192.168.0.200 on the network and what does this mean for your alias interface?